# running row by line in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-formula

I need to make a code that inserts the formula to add some cells in the line, and after adding the value pass to the next row of the selected column. Thank you in advance for your help.

```html
For cont = 1 To 125
    Range("BA1").Select

    Cells(cont, 53).Value = Range("BA2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=RC[-1]+RC[-2]+RC[-3]+RC[-4]+RC[-5]+RC[-6]+RC[-7]+RC[-8]+RC[-9]+RC[-10]+RC[-11]+RC[-12]+RC[-13]+RC[-14]+RC[-15]+RC[-16]+RC[-17]+RC[-18]+RC[-19]+RC[-20]+RC[-21]+RC[-22]+RC[-23]+RC[-24]+RC[-25]+RC[-26]+RC[-28]+RC[-30]+RC[-32]+RC[-34]+RC[-36]+RC[-38]+RC[-39]+RC[-40]+RC[-41]+RC[-42]"


    Next cont
```

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA for this?

Comment: @ScottCraner NICE , please post as "ANSWER"

Comment: @ShaiRado Congrats on hitting 20k!

Answer (score 2):

No loop needed, just use this one line;

```
Range("BA2:BA125").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-42]:RC[-1])"
```